# IntelliJ JSF - Página é aberta em branco

Tags: java, jsf, maven, intellij-idea

## O que eu fiz

Eu criei um projeto **Maven** e adicionei o módulo do **JSF**, entretanto, mesmo com a biblioteca baixada.

## O que está acontecendo

Quando executo meu projeto usando o **Tomcat**, a página **olamundo.xhtml** vem em branco.

A URL deveria vir do seguinte modo `http://localhost:8888/projeto-teste-livro/olamundo.jsf`, mas ela vem bem diferente `http://localhost:8888/projeto-teste/web/olamundo.xhtml`. Parece que o projeto não está sendo identificado como uma aplicação **JSF**.

## O que estou tentando fazer

Estou apenas recriando um pequeno teste que fiz no **Eclipse** para poder comparar usando a IDE **IntelliJ**.

## Meu Ambiente

#### Pasta do Projeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Configurações da Aplicação

Apesar de não existir um subitem dentro de *Web*, percebam que ele já identifica que possuo a biblioteca do **Mojarra** baixada aqui no projeto.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupid-teste</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifacit-teste</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

#### Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <!--   -->
    <display-name>projeto-teste</display-name>

    <!-- Indica que o JSF(FacesServlet) está instalado e responderá as requisições -->
    <servlet>
        <servelet-name>Faces Servlet</servelet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Mapeamento dos sufixos dos arquivos do front end -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Indica a fase de desenvolvimento do projeto. Com o "development", exceptions terão maior descrição -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Campos do formulário submitados em branco serão tratados como nulos -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Indica que campos de data e hora utilizarão o fuso horário definido no sistema. -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!--
        Defini quais arquivos serão exibidos(em ordem de prioridade), caso o endereço
        requisitado não especifique um arquivo diretamente
    -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!--   -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jvnet-nexus-releases</id>
            <name>jvnet-nexus-releases</name>
            <url>http://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <!--  -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!--   -->

</web-app>
```

#### olamundo.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Teste Inicial JSF</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:outputText value="Olá Mundo" />
        <p>asdsadsa</p>
    </h:body>
</html>
```